# Understanding test suites

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest

I'm learning scalatest and have a question about suites. I want to test a

```
class ByteSource(val src: Array[Byte])
```

And logically I splitted the test cases into the following two:

1. Empty byte source
2. Non empty byte source

The question is if it's correct to split the cases into different suites like this:

```
class ByteSourceTest extends FunSpec with Matchers{
    describe("empty byte source operations"){
        //...
    }

    describe("non-empty byte source operations"){
        //...
    }
}
```

Or `FunSpec` is not quite suitable for such a case?

Comment: Per my understanding, there are no such obligations. You choose what seems correct to you, and go with that. From my point of view, yours design is fine, I'd do the same.

Comment: @dveim Thanks for the response! I was not sure about if it's some sort of idiomatic use of `FunSpec`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FunSpec` is designed to provide minimal structure so there are no hard rules here. An example of opinionated structure would be `WordSpec`. One suggestion I would make is to clearly identity the subject of your test by having an outer `describe("A ByteSource")`:

```
class ByteSourceTest extends FunSpec with Matchers {
  describe("A ByteSource") {
    describe("when empty") {
      val byteSource = new ByteSource(new Array[Byte](0))

      it("should have size 0") {
        assert(byteSource.src.size == 0)
      }

      it("should produce NoSuchElementException when head is invoked") {
        assertThrows[NoSuchElementException] {
          byteSource.src.head
        }
      }
    }

    describe("when non-empty") {
      val byteSource = new ByteSource(new Array[Byte](10))

      it("should have size > 0") {
        assert(byteSource.src.size > 0)
      }

      it("should not produce NoSuchElementException when head is invoked") {
        noException shouldBe thrownBy {
          byteSource.src.head
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Having test subject the output seems to read like a specification in natural language:

```
A ByteSource
  when empty
  - should have size 0
  - should produce NoSuchElementException when head is invoked
  when non-empty
  - should have size > 0
  - should not produce NoSuchElementException when head is invoked
```